# Does Flash Player 10 use a new (unreleased) AMF specification?

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3

Is there an official Adobe update to the AMF3 specification?  There appear to be changes to the way the flash.utils.Dictionary object is encoded in AMF in Flash Player 10, but the AMF specification has not been updated on Adobe's website.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't found an official update to the spec, but there is a comment in this ticket that indicates Dictionary has been added as a new AMF type with a marker of 17.

https://bugs.adobe.com/jira/browse/BLZ-317

The specification should be updated with the new types that have been added, but it doesn't appear that the Adobe team has released that specification.  I added a ticket for Adobe.

https://bugs.adobe.com/jira/browse/FP-3172